# How can i stick <span> or <div> in the same line

Tags: html, css, inline

If i have 4 div(s) or 4 span(s), and each of them have a different color, and a width of 25% for each, and displaying them in the same line by using display:inline-block, question is, how can i let them in the same line(without pushing the next element down) in case of i increased the percentage of one of them. So let's say, the screen is like this ( Red Black Yellow Pink ) *doesnt matter for the height*, So the screen will be full of the 4 colors (on the X-axis), but if i increased, let's say, the width of the Black one up to 50%, the other 2 colors will be pushed to down, and i don't want that, i want them to move right with the X-axis, so how can i do that?

Sorry for making it that long, just wanted to be clear for all.
Thank you already.

Comment: I stopped reading after 1 line - Please read the help section on how to ask questions.

Comment: If the total % width goes over 100%, then they won't fit on the same line.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to set the parent to not allow word-wrapping. Inline-block elements are treated as text content with regard to the flow, so doing this will prevent them from wrapping onto the next line, even if they are too long to fit.

You may also want to set it to hide the overflow, depending on exactly what you want it to do.

So you need the following:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

The other option (which seems more sensible in reality) is to make sure that your elements always add up to 100%. So if you increase on to 50%, decrease the others at the same time to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use flex-box.

Is this what you had in mind? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrzQLV

On the black column I added `flex-grow: 2` which makes it twice as big. incrementing that value would grow it.

Comment: Yes, but the way you wrote it is kinda advanced! i thought i can make the X-axis unlimited, or something like that, still a beginner to consider how to do that lol. Anyways, thank you for your time.

Comment: You can add more if you want to. Most of the CSS is only there for decoration purposes but you can certainly add more divs. Observe https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrzQLV

Using `:nth-child` is exactly how you target specific divs. Flexbox is really the right way to go about this.  http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox Modern browsers support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the four divs or spans on one line using inline-block and float left. The line would have to equal 100% for your content to not go down to a new line even with floats. Flexbox would help if you are trying to get all your content to dynamically fit. It would still use only 100% of the row though. Not all browsers support flexbox.

```css
.outter-div {
     width:100%;
     display:block;
     position:relative;
     height:100%;
     margin:0 auto;
     }
    
    
    .one,.two,.three,.four {width:25%;
     display:inline-block;
     float:left;position:relative;
     height:100%;text-align:center;}
     .one {background-color:blue;}
     .two {background-color:green;}
     .three {background-color:red;}
     .four {background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="outter-div">
      <div class="one"><p>Content 01</p></div>
      <div class="two"><p>Content 02</p></div>
      <div class="three"><p>Content 03</p></div>
      <div class="four"><p>Content 04</p></div>
    </div>
```